# Function getopt in C

Tags: c, getopt

I have a problem with situation when I don't write parameters, which I would like to be essential.

```
  while ((choice = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b:")) != -1) {
    switch (choice) {
    case 'a' :
      printf("a %s\n", optarg);
      break;
    case 'b' :
      printf("b %d\n", optarg);
      break;
    case '?' :
      if (optopt == 'a')
        fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
      break;
    }
  }
```

When I write `./a.out -b test` I don't see `fprintf()` message

Comment: Ok. You have a problem. But, what's the problem?

Comment: When I write ./a.out -b test I don't see fprintf message

Comment: Check the value of `choice` before `switch`? It does work here

Comment: But you did replace the `%d` with a `%s` in the second `printf()`, didn't you? ;-) @another.anon.coward

Comment: @alk: Yea... :S. couldn't look away when `gcc` spewed `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to track whether or not option `-a` has been used yourself - `getopt()` doesn't have a rich enough spec to capture that information.  Something like:

```
int opt_a_found = 0;

while ((choice = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b:")) != -1) {
switch (choice) {
case 'a' :
  opt_a_found = 1;
  printf("a %s\n", optarg);
  break;
case 'b' :
  printf("b %d\n", optarg);
  break;
case '?' :
  if (optopt == 'a')
    fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
  break;
}
}

if (!opt_a_found) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Option -a is required.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `printf()` when wrting `fprintf()`:

I might be wrong, but as far as I remember `optarg` is `char *` so you should use `%s` also in your second `printf()`.

In case you really meant `fprintf()` please explain why you expect to see it.

Comment: It should still print, not saying it'll make any sense :)

Comment: No, it not necessarily needs to print something, as passing data on the stack not matching the `printf()`-formatter tends to provoke undefined behaviour, which includes to not get anything at all. @sixlettervariables

Comment: Now I'm testing using getopt. After that I'm going to end program in this situation

Comment: @alk: I agree its undefined and should be fixed, but usually it'll print something then have a nice error due to the stack not being cleaned up properly. Regardless, I think the OP really meant `fprint` because the `printf` statements work.

Comment: At least under linux, using a fairly recent `glibc`, I (sometimes) observed exactly the behavior the OP describes. @sixlettervariables

Comment: But not seeing the `fprintf()` is ok, following the definition for option `-b` (`"a:b:"`), isn't it? Or am I mixing up the sysntax `getopt()` uses? @sixlettervariables

Answer (score 0):

because your `fprintf` is under this condition `if (optopt == 'a')` which will be false when optopt is `'b'`

```
if (optopt == 'a')
    fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
break;
```

try

```
if (optopt == 'a' || optopt == 'b' )
    fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
break;
```

Comment: This would be relevant if option `-b ` was missing it's argument, but the OP's test case is `-b test` .... *sigh*

Comment: @alk - thanks. I missed the `test` in question, I see `fprintf` only under this if and that is enabled only for `'a'`. Edited the question :-)